# Type error in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to build a list of the indices where the list minimums occur.

```
let rec max_index l =
let rec helper inList min builtList index = 
match inList with
| [] -> builtList
| x :: xs ->
    if (x < min) then
        helper xs x index :: builtList index + 1 //line 63
    else
        helper xs min builtList index + 1
in helper l 100000 [] 0;;
```

It's giving me the following error for line 63.

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list -> 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list -> 'a list
```

An expression was expected of type 'a? I'm not sure why it's saying that. My guess it it has something to do with the `index::builtList`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        helper xs x index :: builtList index + 1 //line 63
    else
        helper xs x index min index + 1
```

The problem you're having is that you're trying to pass a non-list to your helper function on line 65 (`min`) whilst trying to pass an `int list` to the same parameter on line 63. Try replacing `min` with `[min]` or `min::[]`.

Edit:

After the update, the issue is that function calls are left associative and higher precedence than binary operators (see [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html)), so `helper xs x index` would execute before `index :: builtList` and likewise `helper xs x index :: builtList` would execute before `index + 1`.  To get the correct order of evaluation, you need to put parenthesis around the other function calls i.e. `::` and `+` plus their parameters like this:

```
        helper xs x (index :: builtList) (index + 1) //line 63
    else
        helper xs x index min (index + 1)
```

Comment: I actually miscopied those two lines. I've updated it. Same error though

Comment: One other thing I was hoping you could help with.. do you know how to make it more type safe/polymorphic? Right now when I run it I'm getting `This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int` - line 62

Comment: @user2079802 you're getting that for `if (x < min) then`?

Comment: I think it's saying that you're comparing an int to a float.  The only thing I can guess is that your parameter `l` has floats in it.

Answer (score 3):

You need some parentheses. Function calling binds tighter than binary operators. So

```
if (x < min) then
    helper xs x (index :: builtList) (index + 1)
else
    helper xs min builtList (index + 1)
```